# "CUDA out of memory" in PyTorch

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I have
16 GB of RAM
AND GPU 2060 6 GB

trying to run the ["transformers gpt2 model"](https://huggingface.co/gpt2) on GPU

when I run  the code with CPU its work but take a long time (2 - 4) min
so I tried to move to GPU but there is an "out of memory" issue

```
import torch
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel , GPT2Tokenizer
 
#import torch

print(device)
 


# %% [markdown]
# ### Load Model

# %%
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2-large')

 

model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2-large' , pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id )

 
model.to(device) ## model to GPU


# %%
tokenizer.decode(tokenizer.eos_token_id)

# %% [markdown]
# ### Tokenize the text

# %%
sentence = "workd war 2"
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(sentence , return_tensors = 'pt')

# %%
input_ids = input_ids.to(device)
#prompt = prompt.to("cuda")


# %%
tokenizer.decode(input_ids[0])

torch.cuda.empty_cache()

# %%
print(tokenizer.decode(input_ids[0][1]))
#print(tokenizer.decode(input_ids[0][2]))
#print(tokenizer.decode(input_ids[0][3]))
#print(tokenizer.decode(input_ids[0][4]))

# %% [markdown]
# ### Generate and Decode Text

# %%
output = model.generate(input_ids, max_length = 500, num_beams = 5,no_repeat_ngram_size  = 2 , early_stopping = True) 
 
 
# %%
output[0]


# %%
print(tokenizer.decode(output[0] , skip_special_tokens = True))

# %% [markdown]
# ### Output Result

# %%
text = tokenizer.decode(output[0] , skip_special_tokens = True)


# %%
with open('okokok.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

the error message I got

```
\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\gpt2\modeling_gpt2.py", line 235, in forward
    present = torch.stack((key.transpose(-2, -1), value))  # transpose to have same shapes for stacking
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 12.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 3.91 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 4.57 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

max memory used is 9 GB when running the code is that because of GPU memory or RAM memory?
It must use the GPU for processing

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Unfortunately, the models do consuem quite a bit of memory; without >12 GB of GPU RAM, you probably won't get to use any but the smallest checkpoints (rougly <500MM parameters, I would estimate).

Answer (score -1):

You can try `Nvidia-smi` to make sure which Pid takes out 3.91 GiB memory. Then use `kill -9 -pid_number` to release the memory for GPU. You may run the script smoothly.